# <a> tag within a table <td> tag

Tags: html, html-table, hyperlink

I have created Two Tables, in Table-2, i have just added a  tag.
The Cell where the  tag is used automatically expands. 
Will anyone kindly explain whats going on. 
what is the best way to automatically adjust the column sizes equally when adding the  tag within a cell.
I want Table-2 to look like Table-1 after adding the  tag.

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="40">
    <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange" colspan="5" height="auto" align="center">
      <p>Table-1</p>
    </td>

    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="40">
    <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange" colspan="5" height="auto" align="center">
      <p>Table-2</p>
    </td>

    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"><a href="http://www.google.com">Search</a></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use :

```
td{
width:20%
}
```

```css
td{
width:20%;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="40">
    <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange" colspan="5" height="auto" align="center">
      <p>Table-1</p>
    </td>

    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="40">
    <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange" colspan="5" height="auto" align="center">
      <p>Table-2</p>
    </td>

    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="40">
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"><a href="http://www.google.com">Search</a></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
      <td style=" border: 2px dotted orange"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table-layout property. In your HTML it would look like this:

```
<table width="100%" style=" table-layout: fixed">
```

...but ideally it should be in your CSS stylesheet.